# Directory index full!

Tags: files

I have a problem about Linux file count failure, that problem depends on exceed max file number of system, when I get that error expand file size and makeshift that problem. How can I find which files I should delete?

`df -i` result is attached, when IUse% 100% and I get that error.

[image]

Comment: Your terminology feels a little strange (to me), but there is no actual clear definition of inode. Inodes are 'blocks' (maybe thinking of them as clusters if you use NTFS), and a disk when formatted is divided into a set number of blocks/inodes & once used up, no more files can be created on that file-system (not just a single directory on the file-system, the whole file-system is impacted; though an error message may refer to only the directory where it's noted due to programmers chosen error message). I'd normally use `du` (disk usage which has --inodes option)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is no space left on the device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225990/there-is-no-space-left-on-the-device)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)

Comment: actually my problem exceed number of the file number. Althougt when exceed that space, i can't signing in because can not create session. I'm not expert on that os.

Comment: You should be able to login using a text terminal (a GUI session will require space available in $HOME yes, text terminal logins have no such restriction). When you format the file-system is when you set the inode parameters though most of use defaults which are consequence of *fs* selected, size etc (creating extra partitions for specific needs to aid maintenance if we deem it necessary etc but that's all done at setup time to prevent/reduce this issue during operation)

Comment: i solved my problem,
- I find file(which has a bilion of file), that files store session information about users, so i delete that files with command find (/home/admin/tmp -mtime +90 -exec rm -f {} \;),